# How to find documentation for available standard methods in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python, and while it's a pretty simple language, I'm having a hard time finding a solid and easy to read language reference that lists all the supported build-in methods and libraries that come with the installation. The main documentation site is confusing. There's more info about what's deprecated than what's recommended. I tried using pydoc to find method usage. For example, I want to see a simple list of all the methods that are part of the string class (e.g. replace(), toupper(), etc). But I'm not sure how to use it to list the methods, or to list a method and its usage. What do people use for a quick reference that works?

When I do something like 'pydoc string', I see a message that says "Warning: most of the code you see here isn't normally used nowadays.
    Beginning with Python 1.6, many of these functions are implemented as
    methods on the standard string object. They used to be implemented by
    a built-in module called strop, but strop is now obsolete itself."

So while there's info about the method replace() there, I'm worried that it's not the right info based on that warning. How can I see the methods of the standard string object?

Comment: you can use dir(yourObject) to see all it's methods and then play with them.  E.g. dir("I am a string")

Comment: What is dir, and where do I type it? I'm just looking for a python 2.7 reference that's easy to read, whether it be a website or preferably like a man page type thing. That's what I thought pydoc is supposed to be.

Comment: open the python console. To open it you can search for it or you can open cmd and type python to enter the python shell. EDIT: dir is a method that lists all the methods that are available for an object, even the "private" one ( ones starting with _)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to see all the string object methods that are not deprecated? And then an example of how to see a method's usage?

Comment: look up how to enter the python shell then just type dir("s") and it should output this: ['__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format'] .. just a few of them since I cant post too much in comments

Comment: the ones bolded are actually starting with __ and ending with __

Comment: Hmm, kind of a strange way to get documentation. So I need to pass an object to dir() to get its methods, then exit out of python shell and then use pydoc obj.method to get the usage. Is that the most convenient way besides using their online doc?

Comment: well, I know it sounds funny but most of them are intuitive. I use it quite often, and for the more ambiguous ones I just google them.

Comment: You see that warning because you are looking at the documentation for a module, not a class.  You should be using `pydoc str`.  You can also use the `help` function in the Python console.  Just as with `dir`, you can pass it any object, but be aware that passing it a string is a special case that makes it look up the contents of the string rather than the string object itself.  @limbo

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the online documentation? I would not in a million years recommend getting documentation with `dir`. At the very least, if you're working on the console and only the console, you should be using the builtin `help` instead. Here is [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) conveniently with other non-deprecated string built-ins. The Python 3 docs are organized a bit better. If you're new to Python, you should be using that anyway.

Comment: Any reason you're googling for [outdated Py1.6 documentation](http://pydoc.org/1.6/) and not [latest Py3.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/)?

Comment: @zondo well thats something new. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: "I'm having a hard time finding a solid and easy to read language reference that lists all the supported build-in methods and libraries that come with the installation." <--- that's exactly what the online docs are

Comment: @limbo: You probably would have noticed it if you had read the documentation :-)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist What you sent me is under section 7.1.6 Deprecated String Functions. Maybe I'm not understanding their doc format, but I was assuming that everything in that section is deprecated. Also, someone told me not to bother with Python 3 because most 3rd party modules don't work with it. Doesn't everyone use 2.7? That's what's installed on my mac.

Comment: There is slight misunderstanding, there are two concepts here, [methods on built-in `str`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) and [content of `string` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#module-string). And indeed, some functions from string module was moved to methods in `str` built-in (and, subsequently, deprecated in module). It still does not explain why would you use docs for legacy Python version instead up-to-date one. Yes, some projects (especially old enough) use Python 2.x but most of new code is produced in Python 3.x.

Comment: @u84six "Someone" told you something that's severely outdated. Believe me, I stuck with Python 2 longer than most, but it's 2016 now. "Most 3rd party modules don't work with it" hasn't been true since 2012. I'm guessing that person doesn't actually have much experience working with Python 3. http://py3readiness.org/

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I read the book Learn Python The Hard Way and I think it was published in 2013. This guy says to avoid Python 3 like the plague. It kind of got me worried thinking that I'd be learning something that no one uses.

Comment: Better than that, avoid that book like the plague.

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://python3statement.github.io

Comment: @u84six "Leary Python The Hard Way" is a good tutorial in some ways but most people have big problems with it. He does some stuff that's absolutely terrible, esp. in a tutorial aimed at brand new users. It will teach you bad habits. (And even in 2013, that opinion was outdated. Should tell you something right there.)

Comment: Here are some of the problems with that book: http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Answer (score 2):

Documentation about standard functions:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Documentation about standard libraries:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dir()` and `help()`. i.e. :

From python shell :

```
>>> import math
>>> dir(math)
['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'erf', 'erfc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'gamma', 'hypot', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'trunc']
>>> help(math.tan)
```

Will print :

> ```
> Help on built-in function tan in module math:
>
> tan(...)
>     tan(x)
>
>     Return the tangent of x (measured in radians).
> ```

(press "q" to exit the help page)

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Another solution from the shell :

```
$ python -m pydoc sys
```

Then press "q" to exit.

Comment: And why "should" you use this over, say, the online documentation?

Comment: You could*. It is a solution. (sorry my bad english) It will be as the user like.

Comment: Fair point -- upvoted. Just making sure we aren't missing the real issue here which seems to be a localized dislike of the online docs caused by (1.) using a severely outdated version and (2.) confusing the `string` module with string objects.